# Mapping of open subsets of product spaces.

Tags: general-topology, product-space

Let each $(A_i,T_i) = (\{0,2\}, T_{discrete})$ and define $\phi : \prod (A_i, T_i) \rightarrow [0,1]$ with $\phi (<a_1, a_2, ...>) = \sum^{\infty}_{i=1} \frac{a_i}{2^{i+1}}$.

If we let $W = \{a_1\} \times \{a_2\} \times ... \{a_N\} \times A_{N+1} \times A_{N+2} \times ...$

What is $\phi (W)$?

It seems to be $\frac {a_1}{2^2} +\frac {a_2}{2^3} + ... + \frac {a_N}{2^{N+1}}  + \frac{\{0,2\}}{2^{N+2}}$ + ... ?  but this doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: You’re right: as you’ve written it, it doesn’t really make sense. $W$ contains infinitely many different points of the product, each of which is a sequence of $0$s and $2$s, and $\varphi[W]$ contains the images under $\varphi$ of all of these sequences. Thus,

$$\varphi[W]=\left\{\frac{a_1}{2^2}+\frac{a_2}{2^3}+\ldots+\frac{a_N}{2^{N+1}}+\sum_{n\ge N+1}\frac{a_n}{2^{n+1}}:a_n\in\{0,2\}\text{ for each }n\ge N+1\right\}\;.$$

Now notice that

$$\frac{a^n}{2^{n+1}}=\begin{cases}
\dfrac0{2^{n+1}}=\dfrac0{2^n},&\text{if }a_n=0\\
\dfrac2{2^{n+1}}=\dfrac1{2^n},&\text{if }a_n=2\;,
\end{cases}$$

so if we set $b_n=\frac{a_n}2$ for $n\ge 1$, we can rewrite $\varphi[W]$:

$$\varphi[W]=\left\{\frac{b_1}{2^1}+\frac{b_2}{2^2}+\ldots+\frac{b_N}{2^N}+\sum_{n\ge N+1}\frac{b_n}{2^n}:b_n\in\{0,1\}\text{ for each }n\ge N+1\right\}\;.$$

At this point it’s very helpful to think of the elements of $\varphi[W]$ interms of their binary representations: for any specific choice of values of the $b_n\in\{0,1\}$, the sum of the infinite series

$$\frac{b_1}{2^1}+\frac{b_2}{2^2}+\ldots+\frac{b_N}{2^N}+\sum_{n\ge N+1}\frac{b_n}{2^n}\tag{1}$$

is simply the real number whose binary representation is

$${0.b_1b_2\ldots b_Nb_{N+1}\ldots\,}_{\text{two}}\;:\tag{2}$$

**by definition** the binary expansion $(2)$ means the sum of the series $(1)$. Thus, $\varphi[W]$ is the set of all real numbers that have binary expansions starting $0.b_1b_2\ldots b_N$.

- What is the smallest such number?
- Is there a largest such number? If so, what is it? If not, what is the supremum (least upper bound) of all such numbers?

Once you’ve answered those questions, you should be able to describe $\varphi[W]$ in very simple terms.

Comment: So:

Question 1: $\sum_{n \ge N + 1} \frac{\{0,2\}}{2^{n+1}}$ is defined as $\sum_{n \ge N+1} \frac{a_n}{}2^{n+1} : a_n \in \{0,2\}, \forall n \ge N +1 $?

Question 2:  Because if either $a_n = 0$ or $b_n = 0$ case we add nothing to the sum and therefore we can replace it with the only viable option which would be $a_n = 1$ or $b_n =1$?

Question 3:  So this would be a map onto [0,1]?

Comment: @Oliver: No, $\sum_{n\ge N+1}\frac{\{0,2\}}{2^{n+1}}$ isn’t defined: it’s simply incorrect notation. It doesn’t actually mean anything. The elements of $\varphi[W]$ are real numbers, each of which is the sum of an infinite series; that’s what the first displayed formula in my answer says. The rest of the answer is devoted to getting a handle on just exactly which real numbers actually *are* in that set. \\ $\varphi$ maps the whole product onto $[0,1]$, but $\varphi[W]$ is not $[0,1]$.

Comment: So if I was to prove that this is a continuous function, I would need to find an open set $W$ that contains $<a_1, a_2, ... >$ such that $\phi(W) \subseteq U \in T_{[0,1]}$.  If I let $U = (\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{2^{n+1}} - \epsilon, \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{2^{n+1}} + \epsilon)$, I wouldn't be able to use $\phi(W)$ as I did before because it's undefined?  Or

Comment: @Oliver: You don’t need to know whether $\varphi$ is continuous in order to answer this question. It is, but that has no bearing on this question.

Comment: So since the elements of $\phi(W)$ are real numbers, but all elements beyond $n \ge N+1$ are not defined, then $\phi(W)$ is a sum of the numbers up to $N+1$?

Comment: @Oliver: No: $\varphi[W]$ is a **set** of real numbers. For each sequence $a=\langle a_1,a_2,\ldots\rangle$ in the product space, $\varphi(a)$ is a single real number, namely, the sum of the convergent infinite series $\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{a_n}{2^{n+1}}$. $\varphi[W]$ is the set of all real numbers $\varphi(a)$ such that $a\in W$. The sequence $a\in W$ are those whose first $N$ terms are $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_N$ and whose remaining terms can be *any* string of $0$s and $2$s.

Comment: I know it's not recommended to use this other than to clarify or ask for an explanation, but that was exactly what I was confused about.
It's exactly the set of the sum of those fixed $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$, and any string of $0$'s and $2$'s for the remaining series.  That's been bothering me all day.  Thanks a million.  I will put up another question for the continuity.

Comment: @Oliver: You’re welcome. I could tell that there was some misconception, but I wasn’t initially sure just what it was.